# Controlling Turtlebot's sound/noise

Tags: ros, turtlebot, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to control/stop/resume the funny sound that Turtlebot makes when it moves (not the one from the motor & wheels but the "computational" one from somewhere on  `iRobot Create`) ? I suspect it might not even controlled by `ROS` since I don't see any `topic` that seems sound related.

I personally like that sound since it's really "robotic", but it'd be nicer if I can turn it off in certain situation for ex. when I create the map of my office.

---

Update Nov 18) Thanks guys but sounds like the sound I'm talking about is different from what you think of. My turtlebots make this fake, sci-fi, technical sound when it/`Create` moves. And it looks like it comes from the base not from `Kinect`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11977/controlling-turtlebot%27s-sound/noise/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To shed some more light on the subject. I even went as far as to disconnect the speaker on the Create (cut the wire) in order to reduce any sound coming from the base. Now my turtlebot seems quieter moving forward or backwards. The weird blipy Starwars noises seem to have be fixed by my mod but it still makes the noise when rotating in place, but not as loud as before. I am sure the noise you are describing is not related to the Create's speakers. As strange as that might sound. Im sure its the motors or possibly something to with the motor drivers making noise. You can try taping your speaker up and see if the noise you hear is reduced. I'll take some time and investigate the noises agian, and post some more info. --Atom--

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, my experience with the IRobot Create is that it is loud. IMHO But I went as far as to examine the internals of the motors and drive-train and noticed that alot of the noise was due to plastic parts rubbing or touching inside. So I added some small plastic spacers inside the gear case to make some distance away from the motor gears and the encoders. Which I believe is where alot of the funny noise was coming from. But the trick is not to put too much distance away from the encoder and sensor so it still accurate. My turtlebot still makes noise but not nearly as loud as before. But I assume this mod will void your warranty and you may damage the gears,encoders, ect if you are not careful.. I mainly examined the noise due to the interference I was getting when trying to use TTSpeech with turtlebot.  --Atom--

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2011-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely that noise is generated by the servo motor when the velocity command to the create is very small. When servo motors are driven at the low end of the controllable range typically they will make noises like you hear in the create. As you drive the create faster the noise should be less pronounced.

Also you can drive the motors at particular frequencies to produce different noises in general. For example you can make servo motors sing.... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-i9RyROVWHI

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1